# How to build netbsd based mobile os

Tags: netbsd

I'm searching for way to start my own project 
I wanna build a mobile os based on netbsd 
I will use netbsd ARM kernel to make my own SoC 
Os could you give a resources and tools to get started

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.NetBSD.org - the homepage of the NetBSD project has many ressources, starting from how to install the operating system over rebuilding and customizing. General Unix knowledge will help you, depending on what you want to do.

For detailled, in-depth technical questions I recommend using the NetBSD mailing lists, for which there is also an archive at http://mail-index.NetBSD.org.

Answer (score 1):

Check DeforaOS project (www.defora.org) and also this:

http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/punctuation/